# Optimizing storage for an array of addresses

Tags: solidity, storage, arrays, compilation, optimization

When possible, does Solidity optimize a storage array of `address`?

For example, does `address[8]` take up 5 storage slots (160 bytes), or 8 storage slots?

```
contract C {
  address[8] arr;
}
```

If 8 slots are used, is there a way to write the code so that Solidity will compile to only using 5 slots?  Different alternatives are welcome, with preference given to an easy way to access the addresses (such as `arr[2]` instead of twiddling with bytes, but such answers will still be helpful).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the storage is not optimized. We can see this using the debugging tools in browser solidity:

[image]

This is a trace of the `set` function with `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` as arguments. We can see that each address uses exactly one storage slot.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how the compiler make deal with storage in your case. But you can use byte[160] array to store 8 addresses. Here is the code for it. **storeAddress** will save address to **addresses_storage** variable by given **index**, function **getAddress** will get an address, previously stored by **index**.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract Addresses5Storage {

    //---------------------BEGIN Code to copy-paste--------------   

    byte[160] private addresses_storage;

    function storeAddress(address addr,uint index)
    {
        uint k=0;
        for (uint i=index*20;i<=(index+1)*20-1;i++)
            addresses_storage[i]=byte((bytes20(addr)<<8*k++)&bytes20(0xff00000000000000000000000000000000000000));    
    }

    function getAddress(uint index) constant
    returns (address)
    {   
        bytes20 addr;
        uint k=0;
        for (uint i=index*20;i<=(index+1)*20-1;i++)
        {
            addr^=bytes20(addresses_storage[i])>>8*k;
            k++;
        }
        return address(addr);
    }

    ////////////////////END Code to copy-paste///////////////////


    //-----------------BEGIN testing stuff code-----------------  
    address[8]  addresses=
        [0x61c2571ac2c83f399a23a1723b3e08ad933267f0,
        0xfa8d3048d236be994a6443fab364c35d2c9934ed,
        0xb6f31f166af597ca40f2f703a4b6b4260124b762,
        0x97b503b07e13e9c104f6091e44bc922f0fd618f6,
        0x3fac7be8070078884feddd5fa2aab30afd7c7ae5,
        0x6fac7be8070078884feddd5fa2aab30afd7c7ae6,
        0x7fac7be8070078884feddd5fa2aab30afd7c7ae7,
        0x8fac7be8070078884feddd5fa2aab30afd7c7ae8];

    //Tests store and get functions. Usage test
    function testStoreAndGet (uint index)
    returns (address)
    {
        storeAddress(addresses[index],index);
        return (getAddress(index));
    }
    //////////////////END testing stuff code//////////////////////
}
```

**UPDATE:** Unfortunately I can not examine bytecode. But based on solidity documentation (http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html), where it is said:

1. The first item in a storage slot is stored lower-order aligned.
2. Elementary types use only that many bytes that are necessary to store them.
3. If an elementary type does not fit the remaining part of a storage slot, it is moved to the next storage slot.
4. Structs and array data always start a new slot and occupy whole slots (**but items inside a struct or array are packed tightly according to these rules**).

And also

5. **The elements of structs and arrays are stored after each other, just as if they were given explicitly**

I can do some assumptions: type *address* is elementary type and it size is 20 bytes. So if you store it to staticly sized array it becomes the first element in new slot (because of 4) and free space left in this slot is 12  bytes. It is less then *address* size, that's why the next *address* element should be stored in the next slot (because of 3) and so on. So to store N addresses in array you'll need N memory slots. 
Unlike *address* type, *byte* elements should densely fill slots, and the number of slots to store N addresses must be ceil(N*20/32)

**P.S.** In theory this should work as explained above, but it would be cool if someone examine bytecode.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  I was hoping someone who examines bytecode would be able to explain more about Solidity's storage slots.  Now it would be interesting to also see how many slots `byte[160]` uses.

Comment: @eth answer was updated